# AVR Programing : Chip enable program error

Tags: avr

I am working on avr controllers for a while, but I have problem with "progisp" avr programming software. When I buy a new micro-controller like atmega32 it can be programmed properly for a while but after some days, suddenly I want to reprogram it. Progisp shows the error "Chip Enable Program Error". I use USB programmer. For better understanding here is an image of progisp software.

[progisp software error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfQy7.jpg)

I have searched the internet a lot to find a solution but there wasn't a proper and useful solution for my problem. I am sure that my micro-controllers are fine and not damaged because they work as they programmed but I am unable to reprogram them.
I really thank you if you have any solution to help me.

Comment: Ah, So there isn't anybody to help me, PLEASE.

Comment: I can see that some lockbits are set, isn't it the reason why you can't program anymore ?

Comment: But lock bits are disabled, You mean that in the picture i have attached this happened?

Comment: I'm not sure though let's suppose they are locked. So how can i fix it?

Comment: Or just how can i find out?